# What does it mean to have android.intent.action.MAIN in Android manifest without LAUNCHER category?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a project with an Android manifest that has two activities with android.intent.action.MAIN for its intent filters, one with LAUNCHER and one without. In fact, the second activity has no category set at all. How does one launch the activity without LAUNCHER category?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the first activity would have to call `startActivity()` to start up the second activity.

There may be other scenarios (e.g., Android 7.0 app shortcuts, notifications), but none of those would require the `MAIN` action. Similarly, `MAIN` can be tied with other categories (e.g., `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` for Android TV), though I assume that's not the case here, since you did not mention it.

Comment: The activity without LAUNCHER category is a Chromecast related activity. If the first activity has to call to start the second, why would the second one need to be labeled as MAIN?

Comment: @Boon: Unless there's something Chromecast needs it for, it would not need the `MAIN` action.